# magento cant create categories

Tags: categories, magento-1.7

Recently I can not edit or add new categories in my magento shop. The whole layout seems destroyed. I really do not know what's wrong.

I've already googled a bit and also I've been able to find something (it seems that Google Analytics is to blame), but the solution in [this forum post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/232603/) did not help me because I can not find the `.fastaccess` file on my server.

Also can't upload product images any more, because the button "Browse files" and so on are gone.

Here's an image of the manage categories page of the admin panel: [img http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/2687/unbenannt1lk.jpg](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/2687/unbenannt1lk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know where this problem was coming from. But I did solve it by reinstalling the whole store.